# aws s3 access denied when changing bucket policy for root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am logged in as a `root` user for aws account. A bucket has been created for `static website hosting`. I have also unchecked all the options on `Public access Settings` as you can see in this image below.
[image]

After that I tried to update the bucket policy to this from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html)

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I keep getting `Access denied` Error. I don't get it what have I missed. I have tried following things.

- I have found other SO posts [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496152/aws-s3-bucket-policy-editor-access-denied) which tells to uncheck `block
  new public bucket policies option` which I have already done but
  why does it not work for me?
- I destroyed the bucket and redid everything from scratch but same issue
  persists.
- I also created a new IAM user with roles to access everything. This also didn't solve the issue.
- I can however manually change the s3 objects to `public` through `Make Public` option in s3 menu under `s3 Overview` tab. This has been solving my problem temporarily for now but I have to keep doing this every time I re upload the files.

So my Question is. **Why do I keep getting access denied even for root user?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps and it worked fine for me:

- I created a **new bucket**
- I clicked on the bucket, went into the **Permissions** tab and edited the **Public access settings**
- I turned **off** the two settings under *Manage public bucket policies for this bucket*
- I added a **Bucket Policy** by taking your policy (above) and changed the bucket name to match my bucket
- I successfully **saved** the Bucket Policy

It then gave me a warning note:

> This bucket has public access
>
> You have provided public access to this bucket. We highly recommend that you never grant any kind of public access to your S3 bucket.

I cannot see why you would be receiving *Access Denied*. My only suggestion is to try it with a different browser just in case there's some strange issue.

You could also **add the Bucket Policy via the the AWS CLI**: [put-bucket-policy — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-policy.html)

This also successfully added a Bucket Policy onto my bucket.

Comment: Thank you john, unfortunately even from cli I get the same error. I will try with a brand new aws account just to make sure if this is happening only on my account.