# aws-cdk s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied when deploying bucket with public read access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to set up a static website using an S3 bucket using the cdk. However, when I deploy the stack I receive the error `API: s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied`. The CLI user I am using has administrator permissions.

I have tried to manually create a bucket with the "Static website hosting" property configured, but when I add the following bucket policy, I receive an `Access denied` error, even though I am the root user.

```
 {
  "Id": "PolicyId",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Something similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496152/aws-s3-bucket-policy-editor-access-denied).

I have deselected all the public access settings like is suggested - but I still receive an access denied.

I believe the problem when deploying the cdk code may be related to the problem when creating the bucket manually, but I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: I had a very similar issue which I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144798/why-is-an-admin-account-getting-permission-denied-when-updating-a-bucketpolicy
I was able to "resolve" it by updating to the latest version of CDK (1.32.2). It seems there have been some IAM changes that must've fixed this.

Answer (score 15):

In April 2023 AWS must have changed bucket defaults, a fix for AWS CDK projects would be adding blockPublicAccess together with accessControl props as follows:

import { BlockPublicAccess, BucketAccessControl } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3";
....

```
// Content bucket
const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "Bucket", {
  ...
  blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ACLS,
  accessControl: BucketAccessControl.BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL,
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had the problem you described and your solution fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you. It took me half of the morning to find out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For folks struggling with this error using aws-cdk and already existing bucket:

Take a look if you are not trying to modify bucket policy when you have set `"blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL"` in Bucket properties.

You have to turn it off or remove that property if you want to modify the policy. After deploying (modifying) policy you can set the `blockPublicAccess` property back again.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
        //Create the web bucket and give it public read access
        this.webBucket = new Bucket(this, 'WebBucket', {
            websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html',
            publicReadAccess: true
        });

        //Deploy the frontend to the to the web bucket
        new BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployFrontend', {
            source: Source.asset('../ui/dist'),
            destinationBucket: this.webBucket
        });
```

Also, make sure the "Block public access (account settings)" is turned off in the S3 Console.